# C# ODBC: Improving performance for thousands of select queries

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core, odbc, openedge

The database I am using is Progress OpenEdge. In my program I am taking thousands of serial numbers and querying the database for the information relating to them.

Essentially this code bellow takes ~6000 serial numbers and creates a select query for each serial number and returns a list containing the strings.

```
/// <summary>
/// Builds a list of queries for each serial number in param<c>sn</c>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sn">A list of valid serial numbers</param>
/// <returns>A list of strings where each string is a sql query for a serial number's information</returns>
private static List<string> BuildQuery(List<string> sn)
   {
      return sn.Select(s => "SELECT a.\"Date-Created\", a.\"date-produced\", a.employee, " +
                            "a.\"Item-Code\", a.\"job-number\", a.\"station-produced\", " +
                            "a.\"shift-produced\", a.\"Serial-Number\", a.\"parent-serial\", " +
                            "a.\"gross-wgt\", a.\"qty-base\", a.\"resin-wgt\", " +
                            "a.\"tare-wgt\", a.\"Integer-1\", a.\"unit-number\" FROM " +
                            $"CUSTOM10.PUB.\"imsngsnt\" a WHERE a.\"Serial-Number\" = '{s}'").ToList();
   }
```

And then I loop through the list calling this function ~6000 times.

```
/// <summary>
/// Makes a query to the given connection <c>conn</c> and query <c>sql</c> and returns the information for the serial number <c>sn</c>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="conn">Connection to SNT database</param>
/// <param name="sql">SQL query</param>
/// <param name="sn">The serial number the query pertains to</param>
/// <returns><c>SerialInformation</c> containing the information for Serial number <c>sn</c></returns>
private static SerialInformation MakeQuery(OdbcConnection conn, string sql, string sn)
   {
       var set = new DataSet();
       // Perform all queries
       var adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(sql, conn);

       adapter.Fill(set);
       if (set.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0) return null;
       var info = ConvertDataSet(set);
       // Add starting serial number to info
       info.StartingSerial = sn;
       return info;
    }
```

I know this is horribly inefficient and I would like to know how I can make these queries faster using .NET System.Data.ODBC.

Comment: Well, one obvious botteneck is, that you do this for each and every serial number separately. Now putting all 6000 serial numbers in one query ("WHERE a.\"Serial-Number\" IN ('{sn1}', '{sn2}', [...], '{sn6000}')") probably won't work, but you could try batches of maybe 500 or even just 100, whatever query length will still go through. Assuming this DB allows for "IN" clauses. -- Otherwise, how many rows are in this table/view? Maybe it would be easier to just get _everything_ and then work in-memory...

Comment: That would be better I bet. Pulling all the information is probably a no go. From what I've been told there's 10s of thousands of rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to create a table in the database, create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE search_serial_numbers (
  "Serial-Number" INTEGER 
  -- or is it VARCHAR(n)? 
  -- EXACT SAME TYPE AS "Serial-Number" in the 
  -- CUSTOM10.PUB."imsngsnt" table!
);
```

Then, perform an array insert of the ~6000 rows - in one SQLExecute() call - into the `search_serial_numbers` table.

Then, go - ( I'll write that in plain SQL, you concat the string from within C# as you need):

```
SELECT 
  a."Date-Created"
, a."date-produced"
, a.employee
, a."Item-Code"
, a."job-number"
, a."station-produced"
, a."shift-produced"
, a."Serial-Number"
, a."parent-serial"
, a."gross-wgt"
, a."qty-base"
, a."resin-wgt"
, a."tare-wgt"
, a."Integer-1"
, a."unit-number"
FROM CUSTOM10.PUB."imsngsnt" a 
INNER JOIN search_serial_number b
on a."Serial-Number" = b."Serial-Number"
;
```